# Can I view the implementation of the appendFormat instance method in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'd like to see how `appendFormat` is implemented in Objective-C:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmutablestring/1497308-appendformat

```objc
- (void)appendFormat:(NSString *)format, ...;
```

Is there a way to see the implementation?

I found this:

https://github.com/cjwl/cocotron/blob/master/Foundation/NSString/NSMutableString.m#L111

```objc
-(void)appendFormat:(NSString *)format,... {
   NSString *string;
   NSRange   range={[self length],0};
   va_list   arguments;

   va_start(arguments,format);

   string=NSAutorelease(NSStringNewWithFormat(format,nil,arguments,NULL));
   va_end(arguments);

   [self replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
}
```

But I'm not sure if it's the same as for Cocoa.

I want to see the implementation so I can confirm the runtime. Since `appendFormat` is for mutable strings, I'm assuming `appendFormat`'s runtime is worst case O(n) and amortized O(1), but I'm not sure.

(I'm not an Objective-C Developer.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't see the source code for `-[NSMutableString appendFormat:]` because it's not available outside of Apple.

You can disassemble the Foundation framework to look at the implementation. I did (using Hopper), and the implementation basically works out to this:

```
- (void) appendFormat:(NSString *)format, ... {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, format);
    NSString *string = [[NSString allocWithZone:nil] initWithFormat:format locale:nil arguments:ap];
    [self replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(self.length, 0) withString:string];
    va_end(ap);
}
```

If you look at the disassembly of `initWithFormat:locale:arguments:`, you can see that it calls `_CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux2`. The source code for that (from macOS 10.10.5) is available [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-1153.18/CFString.c.auto.html). Ultimately you'll find yourself down in `__CFStringAppendFormatCore`, in the same file. This function interprets the format string.

You will have to disassemble CoreFoundation to find the implementation of `replaceCharactersInRange:withString:`. It just calls `__CFStringCheckAndReplace`, which is in defined in the same CoreFoundation source file I linked above. You can drill down from there and ultimately find that when CoreFoundation needs to expand the storage allocated for a string, it does so by a factor of 3/2 each time. This is exponential growth, so the total time spent in `replaceCharactersInRange:withString:` is O(n).